# Checking 2 different values from 2 different tables SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables which are StudentAccount and Students.

in login screen, user enters StudentID and Password. Program checks if those values have the same values in StudentAccount table. lf entered ID and Password are true, l want to show something like this: Welcome Alican. (Name Alican will be taken from Students.)

l have thought that the sql code would be like this: Select Name from Students Where StudentID = **StudentAccount.StudentID** AND Password = **StudentAccount.Password**; 
But it is wrong. 
So how can l code it truly ?

Comment: can you post up some sample data from both tables please

Comment: Edit: (Name Alican will be taken from Students.)
Select Name from Students Where StudentID = StudentAccount.StudentID AND Password = StudentAccount.Password

Comment: Just use a `join`...

Comment: You refer to `Accounts` in the `where` clause, but it is not defined in the `from`.  That is malformed SQL.  Think about how to fix that.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT s.name FROM Students s, StudentAccounts a WHERE s.StudentID = a.StudentID AND s.Password = a.Password;
```

Something like this. You need to include both tables in FROM. I named both tables.

Answer (score 1):

Simple join should do what you need

```
SELECT 'Welcome ' + s.Name
FROM Students s
INNER JOIN StudentAccount sa ON s.StudentID = sa.StudentID AND s.Password = sa.Password
```